# PHP: if file doesn't exist then exit script

Tags: php

```
<?php
$filename = '/path/to/foo.txt';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
}
?>
```

That script only checks if a file exists, but how do I do something like this?

```
<?php
$filename = '/path/to/foo.txt';

if (file doesnt exist) {
    exit("Your file doesn't exist");
}
?>
```

Comment: `if (!file_exists($filename)) {`

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry for the stupid question, please bear with me I'm still learning....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As [John Conde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/250259/john-conde) said, you should negate the `file_exists` function:

```
if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    exit("Your file doesn't exist");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

becarefull if you are using CODEIGNITER, dont use `base_url()` inside file path, use normal path